# How to create some timers and show result from them?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have create timer using RXJS:

```
let timer1value = null;
let timeFinish =  30;
let finishDate = new Date();

return timer(1000)
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => new Date() < finishDate),
        finalize(() => {
          timeFinish = finishDate;
        })
      )
      .subscribe((t) => {
      timer1value = t;
});
```

I need to create some timers and show result on the page:

```
{{timer1value}}
```

So, I have added observer to array `this.timers`:

```
this.timers.push(timer(1000)
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => new Date() < finishDate),
        finalize(() => {
          timeFinish = finishDate;
        })
      ));
```

Then how to get in template actual value of each timers in subscription?

````
{{timer2value}}

{{timerNvalue}}```
````

Comment: Jony, wouldn't the new Date in the takeWhile function always be greater than finishDate?
This is just something I have spotted and not a solution to your problem.
Maybe sharing the actual usecase can help us try a different approach or maybe solve the issue with the current code

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. And also timer(1000) will only emit 0 after one second,  so I am not quite sure what he wants to accomplish. Could you elaborate a bit more @Jony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular you can use the [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to show the latest value emitted by Observables.

To show the latest value of the first timer in the array you can write:

```
{{timers[0] | async}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop over the timers array with ngFor and then unwrap the value of the observable with the async pipe

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let timer of timers; let i = index;">
  Timer {{ index }} is {{ timer | async }}<br>
</ng-container>
```